# Binary Tree pre order transversal

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree

I have a data type for a binary tree and a function to calculate its pre order traversal:

```
data BT a = Empty | Fork a (BT a) (BT a)
  deriving (Show)

treePreOrder :: BT a -> [a] 
treePreOrder Empty = [] 
treePreOrder (Fork x l r) = 
  [x] ++ treePreOrder l ++ treePreOrder r
```

I am now trying to generate a list of all the possible trees from a pre order transversal.

```
preOrderTree :: [a] -> [BT a] 
preOrderTree [] = [Empty] 
preOrderTree (x:xs) = 
  [Fork x l r| i <- [0..length xs-1], let (ys, zs) = splitAt i xs, l <- preOrderTree ys , r <- preOrderTree zs]
```

but it gives an empty list of trees:

```
λ> preOrderTree [1,2,3]
[]
λ> preOrderTree [1]
[]
```

Comment: What does "incorrect" mean? Compiler error? If so, include the text of the error. Runtime exception? If so, include an input that triggers it, and the text of the exception. Some input-output pair that differs from your expectation? If so, include the input you tried, the expected output, and the actual output. Something else? If so, describe it in a bit more detail. If providing an input, ideally you would provide the *smallest* input that triggers the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close.  The problem is with:

```
i <- [0..length xs-1]
```

You have excluded `length xs`, but this is a valid split which would put all the items in the left branch.

By omitting it, you've broken the function for singletons.  When you evaluate:

```
preOrderTree[1]
```

you get `length xs-1 == -1`, so the `i <- [0..length xs-1]` generates no trees.  As a result, this small error causes the entire recursion to generate no trees.

With this corrected:

```
preOrderTree :: [a] -> [BT a]
preOrderTree [] = [Empty]
preOrderTree (x:xs) =
  [Fork x l r| i <- [0..length xs], let (ys, zs) = splitAt i xs
             , l <- preOrderTree ys , r <- preOrderTree zs]
```

it works fine:

```
λ> preOrderTree [1]
[Fork 1 Empty Empty]
λ> preOrderTree [1,2,3]
[Fork 1 Empty (Fork 2 Empty (Fork 3 Empty Empty)),Fork 1 Empty (Fork 2
(Fork 3 Empty Empty) Empty),Fork 1 (Fork 2 Empty Empty) (Fork 3 Empty
Empty),Fork 1 (Fork 2 Empty (Fork 3 Empty Empty)) Empty,Fork 1 (Fork 2
(Fork 3 Empty Empty) Empty) Empty]
```